# IBM DB2 with .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, db2

I am having issues connection to IBM DB2 instance with the following nuget package: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.Data.DB2.Core-lnx/1.2.2.100

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  using (DB2Connection con = new DB2Connection("Server=xxx:8471;Database=xxx;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx"))
  {
    try
    {
      DB2Command MyDB2Command = new DB2Command("select * from xxx.xxx", con);
      con.Open();
      var reader = MyDB2Command.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      throw ex;
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine("DONE");
}
```

Result:

> Loading the DB2APP from Appication Assembly Entry point location
>
> Please ensure environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH value is set to
>   /opt/app-root/src/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/clidriver/lib  ,
>   /opt/app-root/src/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/clidriver/lib/libdb2.so
>   LIbrary handle written value is a non zero 15186032

The LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set correctly. A quick printenv shows it is.

Also I start the app with this command:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/app-root/src/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/clidriver/lib:/opt/app-root/src/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/clidriver/lib/libdb2.so" dotnet run
```

I get no errors, the program just hangs forever on the open. I had our database team debug on there end and they see the open connection but can give me no further information. Any ideas?

Comment: Which linux distro detail?  Which *operating-system* runs the (remote) Db2-server?  Have you tried with either a local database or a database that's also running on Linux/Unix/Windows?

Comment: using Debian 9.x. The db2 server is a mainframe ibm db2 instance. I have not tried from a local database, but I am able to connect to the same server with Elixir on the same box using ODBC drivers.

Comment: Do you mean a Z/OS mainframe?  If so, are you going via a Db2-connect gateway, or do you have the relevant licence-file deployed in the nuget installation folder?

Comment: Yes I do mean z/os mainfram. And no i don't have the dbconnect license. If I connect over port 446 then I do get the license error...But my question is, why can I connect just fine on the same box over ODBC with Elixir?  As a side note, I can connect just fine over windows using OLEDB.

Comment: The nuget is a per-application deploy (not per system). Other applications (e.g. ODBC drivers) are independent of the nuget. If you are connecting directly to Z/OS (that is, not connecting indirectly via a separate Db2-connect gateway), you will need a license. Suggest you check that first.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @marianosz no unfortunately

Comment: do you suggest any workaround?